# Is there a way to create a regular xml file with the data extracted from the container file?

Tags: berkeley-db-xml

Is there a way to create a regular xml file({filename}.xml) with the data extracted from the container file({filename}.dbxml)?

I am wondering if there is a BDB XML query that enables the above question.

If that is not possible, please let me know if there is a third-party tool that makes it possible, or if I need to resolve it directly using the API.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do this using XQuery, you use the `fn:doc()` extension function.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/programmer_reference_xml/xquery_doc.html